# How do i create dynamic properties in Model and use in Controller and View. - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am looking for a solution which creates dynamic properties to be create in Model.

I want to use them in my View and Controller.

Can any one have idea, how to create it?

I am having scenario in my project where one page will be having options to be lets say Profile2, Profile5 etc.

Profile 2 can have two URLs to be submit from user.

Profile 5 can have five URLs to be submit from user.

and

So on........

Is there any solution or alternative to do this????

Comment: See the alternative way, i have done, may be useful to someone, even me at this moment. still looking for exact example if some one have.

Answer (score 3):

He Amit , For your situation "I am having scenario in my project where one page will be having options to be lets say Profile2, Profile5 etc.

Profile 2 can have two URLs to be submit from user.

Profile 5 can have five URLs to be submit from use"

You want to put this url in your properties ok.
SO do one thing create a property like this.

```
public List<string> urlList {get;set;}
```

use this in your property andd add url in the list.
you can add n no of urls.

Comment: if you didnt got my poing then ping me I will explaing what i am saying

Comment: <div>
            @for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.urlProperties[i])
                </div>
            }
        </div>

Comment: foreach(string links in Model){}

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what [ViewBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) is for. Its a dynamic property on Controller and View.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Hello, world";
}


<p>@ViewBag.Message</p>
```

This will allow you to send anonymous property values from your Controller to your View. However, if you're looking to post different numbers of values (urls in your example), you should use an IList as your model.

```
@model IList<string>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i])
}
```

Comment: No, ViewBag is not for this. ViewBag is for nothing else than the trash :-) +1 for the strongly typed view model and IList though.

Comment: ViewBag can be easily abused, but when used in moderation, it can be helpful.

Comment: the best usage of ViewBag/ViewData for me is when you never use it. For me the notion of using it in moderation doesn't exist. The fact that you are using it means that you are doing it wrong :-) But that's just me.

Comment: I agree with you for the most part. But there are occasions when my model is a generic collection and I need to display a message to the user. Instead of creating a new ViewModel class I'll simply set a ViewBag property for the message. But now that I've typed this ... I'm starting to agree with you more.

Comment: everyone is free to design his application the way he likes. I just expressed my approach. You expressed yours. I don't agree with yours (even for the situation you described in your previous comment) but I respect it.

Answer (score 1):

Your model should probably store the values in a list. Here is an example explaining how to display and save data for a list property.

[How to interact with List<t> in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324209/how-to-interact-with-listt-in-mvc)

Answer (score -1):

see this is what i have done as an alternative.

Make all divs and other fields in MODEL and use jQuery to work around.

I guess this is an alternative, but not exactly what i want. Still looking for answer. I post this as this can be helpful to some one in future.

Please check below.

```
<div>
        @for (var i = 0; i < ProfileCount; i++)
        {
            <label>
                URL:</label>
            <input type="text" id=@string.Format("URL{0}", i) />
            <label>
                CheckName:</label>
            <input type="text" id=@string.Format("URL{0}CheckName", i) />
            <label>
                Run Check From:</label>
            @Html.DropDownList(string.Format("URL{0}Region", i), (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Regions) 
            <br />
            <span id=@string.Format("URL{0}Result", i)></span>
            <input type="button" value="Create check" id=@string.Format("URL{0}CheckSetup", i)  onclick="getResponseFromUrl('@string.Format("URL{0}')", i);" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete check" id=@string.Format("URL{0}Delete", i) onclick="DeleteCheck('@string.Format("URL{0}')", i);"
                style="display: none" />
            <input type="hidden" id=@string.Format("URL{0}Hidden", i)  />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        }
    </div>
```